# Problems uploading image to MySQL database, it won't make an entry but uploads the image to server

Tags: php, mysql

so I've been working on this for a while now and I can't figure out how to get it to insert into the database. The image uploads and is stored in the servers imgs directory however no trace is found in the database. There are no errors at all. I'm well aware of the SQL injection weaknesses but this is for a private project that is for a prototype, so I'm just aiming for functionality at this point.
Why on earth isn't this working? I feel like it could be skipping the sql query but I don't see why.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root", "0612733771Aa");

try {
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
   if(!isset($_FILES['upload']) || $_FILES['upload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    echo "Error no file selected"; 
}
else {
    $filename = $_FILES['upload']['name']; //yes
    $filetype = $_FILES['upload']["type"]; //yes
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $dir = "imgs/";
    $filetarget = $dir . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);
    $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
    $ext = pathinfo($filetarget, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {
        echo "Please select a valid file.";
        exit;
    }

    $conn->query = ("INSERT INTO images (title, image, description, category) VALUES ('$title', '$filename', '$description', '$category')");  

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $filetarget)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']). " has been uploaded.";

    }
else {
    print "File was not uploaded.";
    exit;
}  
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there anything at all being added to the db? or is it just that one field?

Comment: btw, no idea why you have brackets here `$conn->query = ("INSERT....)");`

Comment: Nothing is being added to the database whatsoever, only the servers imgs folder. Just the way I've been taught at university, worked for other scripts I've done, could be worth removing them?

Comment: make sure that all columns are long enough and of the right type; it could be failing silently.

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot of my database, it should all be alright however I am new to this and a bit out of my depth. https://postimg.org/image/mhv8aswk3/

Comment: there's your problem; you need to use a prepared statement for this and using the PARAM_LOB parameter in PDO for the image column. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php

Comment: This makes sense now, thanks a lot @Fred-ii- I'll look into this now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution thanks to the help of @Fred-ii- the problem was I was not using prepared statements, **the updated code**. I had to switch my entire code to a prepared statement, and make use of the PDO::PARAM_LOB in order to submit a large blob into the database.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$fp = fopen($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$filetype = $_FILES['upload']["type"]; //yes
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$dir = "imgs/";
$filetarget = $dir . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
$ext = pathinfo($filetarget, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project", "root", "0612733771Aa");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images (title, image, description, category) VALUES ('$title', '$fp', '$description', '$category')");
try {
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
if(!isset($_FILES['upload']) || $_FILES['upload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    echo "Error no file selected"; 
    }
else {
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) {
    echo "Please select a valid file.";
    exit;
    }
$stmt->bindParam(1, $title);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $description);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $category);
$conn->beginTransaction();
$stmt->execute();
$conn->commit();
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $filetarget)) {
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['upload']['name']). " has been uploaded.";
}
else {
    print "File was not uploaded.";
    exit;
    }  
}
?>
```

Comment: great but... one would think that I'd of been invited to post an answer ;-)

Comment: Sorry, not trying to steal your glory here!, just thought it would be useful for future users.

Comment: *"not trying to steal your glory here"* - Believe me, it has nothing to do with glory.

Comment: One might think that Fred would know the difference between 'of' and 'have' - just another of life's little disappointments. ;-)